# How do I get my webserver to serve both my html file and the js file that was built via webpack?

Tags: webpack, webserver

I'm trying to write a webserver that will serve a react app that I am building using webpack but I'm running into an issue serving both the html file and the js file that has the very simple react app that I've written.

My html file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root" />
        <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where main.js is the built webpack js file (sorry if my terminology is off, please let me know if this isn't clear). I'm assuming I need to serve both somehow, but I'm unsure of how to do it - or if that is even the right approach to begin with.

For some more context, my react app opens when I open it via the local path on my browser, and I've tested that my webserver serves really simple html files.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The right approach is to let webpack generate .html files with `<script>` tag referencing the .js file built by webpack. Such a .js file is called script bundle. Webpack, being a bundler, builds bundles. The advantage of this approach will become clear later, when you ask webpack to include a hash into the name of the script bundle e.g. `main.<hash>.js`. This helps with versioning. The .html files are served by a webserver. In development webpack-dev-server is used, in production ExpressJS is frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use express.js ,
and create static folders as much as you need (You may need 1 if everything in same  main folder)(I named mines public and dist)
then

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.use(express.static("./dist"));
app.listen(1299, () => {});
```

EDIT : If you need more crude way , you need more improvements like error handling mime types etc.

```
var http = require('http');
const fs = require("fs");
const pathUtils = require("path");

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path1 = pathUtils.resolve(__dirname, "public") + req.url.replace(/\//g, "\\");
    fs.exists(path1, (exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            fs.readFile(path1, "utf8", (error, content) => {
                if (content)
                    res.write(content);
                else if (error)
                    res.write(error)
                res.end();
            })
        } else {
            res.write("NotFound");
            res.end();
        }
    })
    console.log(path1);

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip ahmet! But I'm currently interested mostly in learning about how this stuff works, so I'd like to try to get it to work using a handwritten web server, if possible. I appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: Second option is not recommended though you need to improve code too much